# Django: How can I use subquery and annotate with 2 tables in 2 different databases in Django?

Tags: django, subquery, using, annotate

I have Table 1 in database1 and Table2 in database2.

I try to use annotate and subquery like bellow but it's not work.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Count
from app1.models import Table1
from app2.models import Table2

subquery = Table2.objects.filter(table1_id=OuterRef('id')).values('table1_id').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('count')

queryset = Table1.objects.annotate(table2_count=Subquery(subquery, output_field=models.IntegerField()), using='database1')
```

The error is:
QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): database1.